# How to create real excel file in Classic ASP

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I have been exporting excel files using `application/vnd.ms-excel` option in classic ASP but after downloading when I click `Save As` I see `Save As Type` option = **web page**.

So is there any way to `Save As` by default so the file type can be saved as an "**Excel 97-2003 WorkBook**"? I tried `excel.application` and `owc` but unfortunately neither work for me.

Actually, these options are consuming a lot of CPU memory when I use them.

I am open to using any third party component for excel creation.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use the same file types here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc

Comment: I used to use office writer (http://www.officewriter.com) for this. Expensive but very good. The only problem is they have dropped support for classic asp.

Comment: Sounds like your code is erroring and sending back a HTTP 500.100 which will be `text/html` (web page) content type rather than your expected `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are aware but you can access the Excel DOM using classic ASP as long as you have Excel installed on the web server.

There are limitations to what you can do but if your requirements are simple then it might be the answer you are looking for without the need to purchase expensive components which are starting to become unsupported.

```
Set oExcel = Server.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set oSheet = oBook.ActiveSheet
Set oRange = oExcel.ActiveCell

oRange.Cells(1,1) = "First Column"
oRange.Cells(1,2) = "Second Column"

oBook.SaveAs "workbook.xls"
oBook.Close
oExcel.Quit

Set oExcel = Nothing
```